# CS50 DNA: Selecting the STRs with next()

Tags: python, cs50

I'm working on Problem Set 6: DNA. My approach is to save the different types of STR sequences as "all_sequences", then find the maximum number of repeats for each sequence in "all_sequences".

My question is: Why does next() ensure I will only select the first row of the csv? I understand [1:] is to remove the name column, but how does next() ensure I only select the first row?

```
f = sys.argv[1]  # name of CSV file
t = sys.argv[2]  # name of text file with dna sequence

# Open the CSV file and read its contents into memory.
with open(f, "r") as database:
    index = csv.reader(database)
    all_sequences = next(index)[1:]

    # Open the DNA sequence and read its contents into memory.
    with open(t, "r") as dnaseq:
        s = dnaseq.read()
        actual = [maxrepeats(s, seq) for seq in all_sequences]
    
    print_match(index, actual)
```

Comment: I suggest first taking look at concept of `generator`s in Python. [RealPython](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) provides introduction with examples, [PEP 255](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) provide design rationale behind them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `index` is a `csv.reader` *object* which is an iterator. `next(index)`yields the next element of the iterator (apparently a list). The list is then sliced to omit the first value.

It is strange to see that next is used only once, because this is simply yields the first row of the `index` iterator. It starts making sense when next is called more often.

Comment: Hey Ronald, thanks a lot, that clarified my understanding!

Comment: Glad it helped, success with Python.